# Moving partition to the beginning of the disk

Tags: partitioning

Best way to move `/dev/nvme0n1p2` to the beginning of the dist and utilize the unallocated space?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There's only one way but many "tools" to do the job. As always, in Linux you can't do it from a running system so boot any live session with GParted (only because that's what you're showing) and move it then expand it. **Have backups**.

Comment: Just emphasizing @ChanganAuto comment -- this is an exercise that frequently goes bad -- make a full drive image beforehand.